# How to find nearest tag ahead of commit in git

Tags: git

I am trying to find the nearest tag after a commit in a particular branch.

I am aware that git describe will walk back and find the nearest ancestor with a tag but how do I move in the opposite direction.

For example:

[image: Commit History]

Given commit 2 I would like to return the future tag. Where git describe would return the past tag.

Comment: How are you trying?  Are you writing a script of some sort?  What language/platform is the script?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about `git describe --contains <commit 2> | cut -d'~' -f1`? As that would refer back to `<commit 2>` from the tag by the number of commits, only take the part before `~` as the tag name (given that your tag names do not contain `~`).

Comment: Seems like a reasonable method if you don't mind getting lightweight tags used (I see `--contains` implies `--tags`). I'll note that Vampire's answer also gets lightweight tags. If you want only annotated tags to be used, it's definitely a harder problem (but we can modify the `git tag --contains` to filter out non-annotated tags).

Comment: @torek Why would we want to? What do you have against non-annotated tags? Also OP didn't say he only wants annotated ones.

Comment: If you do it like `git describe --contains <commit 2> | rev | cut -d'~' -f2- | rev`, you can even have tilde characters in your tag names. But then, tilde characters are disallowed in tag names by git, at least for me.

Comment: @Vampire: `git describe` by default only uses annotated tags. I don't really agree with the reasoning in `git tag` documentation, but it says (quote) "Annotated tags are meant for release while lightweight tags are meant for private or temporary object labels. For this reason, some gitt commands for naming objects (like git describe) will ignore lightweight tags by default."

Comment: @torek I see, but still, why should we try to remove the lightweight tags here? Noone said only annotated tags are to be considered. :-)

Comment: @Vampire: tilde is forbidden (along with space, colon, and caret, and various other special cases): see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html

Comment: Well, OP started by talking about `git describe` and didn't mention running it with `--tags`. So it seemed worth noting, at least.

Comment: @torek Ah, good point. I guess he just missed though that only annotated tags are used in that command. *g* But I might be wrong of course. :-) Regarding the tilde, I know, I said it is forbidden. (Except of course one has a local Git build where he lifted this restriction :-D)

Answer (score 3):

Commits' arrows go in the other direction.  Commit 1 does not point to commit 2; instead, commit 2 points to commit 1.  This matters, because...

In your graph you have drawn just four commits, with neither branches nor merges.  That is, you have drawn the following:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- branch-tip
```

(I have switched from numbers to letters, since there are 26 letters and only ten one-digit numbers, not that I'm using up all ten one-digit numbers anyway....)  If you are at commit `B`, it is very easy to go back to commit `A`: that's the direction the arrows point.  It's hard—in fact, impossible without assistance—to go the other way.

The key bit of assistance we need is an identity or locator for a *later* commit.  For instance, using the name `branch-tip`, we can locate commit `D`.  From `D`, we can go back to `C`, then back to `B`, and now we have traced a usable path.

But this graph is too simple.  Let's draw one with a branch in it.  Since we know Git's arrows are all backwards, let's not bother drawing the internal arrows, and just use connecting lines, knowing that when we draw horizontally like this, we can only move leftward.  And, let's put in your tags, too, plus a few more:

```
tag:past
  |
  |   tag:future
  |     | tag:distantfuture
  v     v   v
  A--B--C---D   <-- branch1
      \
       E--F     <-- branch2
       ^  ^
       |  |
       | tag:future3
       |
   tag:future2
```

Now, which future tag would you like to find for commit `B`, `future` or `future2`?  We know you want neither `future3` nor `distantfuture`, but `future2` and `future` are both just one step away from `B`.

The key is that they're one step *in some direction*: towards the tip of `branch1` or towards the tip of `branch2`.  You may wish to pick a direction, and you do that the same way that you help Git find commit `D` or `F` in the first place, by picking an identifier that locates a commit that eventually comes back to `B`.

If you do want to control the direction, you will want to use `git rev-list --ancestry-path` to find commits that are *descendants* of `B` but *ancestors* of the given branch-tip (excluding `B` itself and including the branch tip).

Then, combine this list of commits with something like [Vampire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41727136/1256452), so that you look only at tags pointing to commits on this ancestry path.  That is, throw out of the list of "tags that contain commit B" any tag pointing to a commit that is *not* in the `git rev-list` output.

Note that this won't solve a problem that occurs in the case of a graph with merges as well as branches:

```
     C--D
    /    \
A--B      G--H   <-- branch-tip
    \    /
     E--F
```

Here, if there are tags pointing to commits `D` and `F`, both are equidistant from `B`, yet both are also on the ancestry path leading from `B` to `H`.

Note that [Vampire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41727136/1256452) simply uses *all tags* as the way to locate later commits that could lead back to `B`, using `--contains` to restrict the list to tags that *do*, eventually, lead back to `B`.  The `rev-list --count` method then finds their "distance".  But if there are merges in the graph, this count may be somewhat flawed.  For instance, in this last graph, with the ring of commits, the "distance" from `H` to `B` is really *four*; but there are *six commits* in the path from `H` back to `B`.  It's just that two of them—`C-D` and `E-F`—can be traversed in parallel.

(Note: if you *are* using `--ancestry-path` to limit the testing to tags that point to commits within some particular graph path, the slight flaw in the `git rev-list --count` metric won't matter, as the same counting-flaw will apply to all ambiguities.  It's only a problem if you are *not* using `--ancestry-path`: in this case, a tag containing a merge commit may produce a much higher count than a tag not containing a merge commit, yet actually be "closer" to commit `B`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
git tag --contains <commit 2> | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "$(git rev-list --count <commit 2>..{}) {}"' | sort -n | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Nearest here is determined by amount of commits. If there are multiple ones that have the same distance, it is not guaranteed which one you will get. If you want all with the same smallest distance, remove the `head` call from the pipeline.

**Note:** This might not work optimally in case of merges, if you have branched and merged those branches after the commit in question and have a tag after that merge, commits of both branches would contribute to the amount of commits and thus the distance.

Comment: Not all `xargs` commands have `-i`: you might want the POSIX-y `-I` and `-J` and `-R`, and add `-n 1` to make it run once per line. Or just pipe to a `while read ...` loop. :-)

Comment: @torek What are `-J` and `-R`? I don't find them in the POSIX `xargs` man page or even in the man-page of my `xargs`. And why should I add `-n 1`? Even in the POSIX version `-I` makes this implicitly.

Comment: Hm, maybe they're BSD/MacOS-specific.  `-I` apparently only does five substitutions, so `-R` sets the number. `-I` also sets `-x`, which is also obnoxious, so BSD `-J` is like `-I` but doesn't do the obnoxiousness. :-) The BSD man page claims that `-J` doesn't imply `-n 1` either, although I'm not sure how this works. ... ah, the example makes it clear, and yes, `-J` does not imply `-n 1`.  Anyway, 5 is enough, so the only annoyance is the implied `-x`.

Answer (score 0):

Find the nearest annotated tag:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import fileinput
import subprocess
import sys

# Usage: script-name <commit sha1>

tag = sys.argv[1]
lightweight = True
while lightweight:
    describe = subprocess.check_output(["git", "describe", "--exclude", tag, "--contains", tag])
    tag = describe.partition(b"~")[0]
    lightweight = subprocess.check_output(["git", "cat-file", "-t", tag]) == b"commit\n"
print(tag.decode())
```